# Having ClassCastException when retrieving data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

**I am making an android app which is using Firebase realtime database when i retrieving data i get an ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map**

**Here is my Java Code**

```
 mref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        System.out.println("First Name: " + newPost.get("FirstName"));
                        System.out.println("Last Name: " + newPost.get("LastName"));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

**Here is a logcat**

```
Process: com.firebasedemo, PID: 10509
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
            at com.firebasedemo.MainActivity$1$2.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:75)
            at com.firebase.client.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent(ChildEventRegistration.java:48)
            at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
            at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: dataSnapshot.getValue(); cannot be casted a map! use this instead  Map<String, Object> newPost = new HashMap<String, Object>(dataSnapshot.getValue()); and dataSnapshot.getValue(); returns a map right?

Comment: The exception indicates that you're getting something out that is not a `Map<String,Object>`. Can you either post the JSON of the data you're extracting *or* `System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue().getClass())`?

Comment: Thanks @MicheleLacorte when i changed Map to HashMap its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend against deserializing a `Map<String, Object>` at this stage in your code. The `DataSnapshot` class has methods for traversing the data structure, which will lead to better error messages if they fail:

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    System.out.println("First Name: " + dataSnapshot.child("FirstName").getValue());
    System.out.println("Last Name: " + dataSnapshot.child("LastName").getValue());
}
```

Better still would be to create a class that represents the data and use Firebase's built-in handling of JavaBeans patterns:

```
public class Name {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName();
  }
  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName();
  }
}

public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Name name = dataSnapshot.getValue(Name.class);
    System.out.println("First Name: " + name.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Last Name: " +name.getLastName();
}
```

Note that in the last example, you'll need to store the properties as `firstName` and `lastName`, so that they match the field names. There are ways to control that, but I never bother and just make sure my JSON matches my field names.